# multiple awaits not executing inside async* generators in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I had to do some work around combining streams where the returned streams would either be stream list of query snapshot, or stream lists of document snapshot. In any case I had to combine the streams and output the result in the UI. I chose not to use rxdart and i wasn't creating any special classes for the particular objects I wanted.

I did run into some major issues with async generator methods.

question 1:

The async generator will only await for one function and ignore any other awaits inside the generator function e.g.

when creating a function e.g.

```
  Stream<List> testFunc3(Stream<List> stream, Stream<List> stream2, List<dynamic> anArray,
      List<dynamic> anArray2) async* {
   
    print('testfunc 3');
    List streamList = [];
    List streamList2 = [];
    await for (List<dynamic> a in stream) {
      streamList.clear();
      a.forEach((element) {
        if (anArray.contains(element['name'])) {
          if (anArray2.contains(element['name'])) {
             print('test 1');
            if (!streamList.contains(element)) streamList.add(element);
          }
        }
      });
       yield streamList;
    }

     await for (List<dynamic> a in stream2) {
      streamList2.clear();
      a.forEach((element) {
        if (anArray.contains(element['name'])) {
          if (anArray2.contains(element['name'])) {
           print('test 2');
          }
        }
      });
      yield streamList2;
    }



  }
```

is there a way to get around this behaviour?

question 2:

If I declare multiple variables that are functions which return streams, only the methods that are used in say StreamGroup.merge() are executed. streams not included in the merge never run.
e.g. z never returns a result because testfunc3 is never executed. unless i add z to the StreamGroup.merge().
keep in mind this isn't the whole function, just the relevant sections and i'm aware this method needs to yield a result

```
Stream<List> getStreamPlaces() async* {
       Stream<List> x = this.testFunc2(stream, anArray);
       Stream<List> y = this.testFunc2(textStream, anArray2);
       Stream<List> z = this.testFunc3(radius);
       Stream<List> g = StreamGroup.merge([x, y]);
// yields something 
       }
```

because of these issues i had to do some long winded approaches to filtering and getting the stream output I wanted. Is this a limitation or bug in dart or am i missing some fundamental understanding? Is there a keyword I could have used to force the execution of these methods?

any help would be appreciated.

for question 2. i do remember codewithAndrea briefly mentioned that an optimization of dart or flutter prevents streams from being executed unless they are used in the code but I couldn't find it when I went searching through his vids.

Comment: two awaits: `void main() {
foo().listen(print);
}

Stream foo() async* {
final a = await Future.value(9);
final b = await Future.value(10);
yield a;
yield b;
}`

Comment: @pskink thanks for reviewing the question. I'll try it out tonight. do you have any suggestions on the 2nd question?

Comment: @pskink  i need the function testfunc3() to run the code within it. e.g. testfunc3 async*{ print('hello world') yield whatever}...  this function will never run is my point. I've already tried using print statements which is how i know it never runs unless i add z into the StreamGroup.merge(). I couldn't make sense of why this wouldn't run either which is why its either a bug or I'm missing something fundamental

Comment: "e.g. testfunc3 async*{" - because it is `async*` generator, check https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch - they say: "The stream is created when the function is called, and the function’s body starts running when the stream is listened to"

Comment: @pskink with regards to awaiting a future inside an async generator i did manage to make it work i had another go after looking at your first comment and got it working. however i have updated question 1 because in this example only the first await for executes. This is a more accurate scenario of my issue that i still haven't resolved. so my question now is, can you have multiple await for inside the same async generator?

Comment: you can have `await for(a in streama` followed by `await for(b in streamb` and it will work only if `streama` closes at some point - then the second `await for` executes

Comment: @pskink can you show how you would implement your answers  with respect to the code examples? happy to accept your answers if they work